# Why my code shows NZCE error besides being correct

Tags: java, error-handling, runtime-error, runtimeexception

I am facing an error while soling a question on codechef in JAVA
My code seems logically correct but I am facing some runtime error

This is the question :https://www.codechef.com/problems/CHEFEZQ

That's my code :

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main 
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        for(int j=0;j<t;j++)
        {
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            int k=sc.nextInt();
            int sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
                sum=sum+sc.nextInt();
            }
            if(sum%k == 0)
                System.out.println((sum/k)+1);
            else
                System.out.println(sum/k+sum%k);}
    }
}
```

[Here is the picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmBSu.png)

And here is the error:
[Here is the picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rpgs.png)

Comment: A `NoSuchElementException` on line 7 (where your first `sc.nextInt()` call is) means that `sc.nextInt()` could not read any number from `System.in`. That in turn means taht you probably did not provide any input.

Comment: Can you please see the question once and help me out ?

Comment: The fact that you see the exception stacktrace means that you did not "Submit" the your code but did "Run" the code. It seems that (at least for this problem) you **must** provide your own custom input if you want to "Run" your code.